# Using Linq lambdas, how can I get the first item in a two-key-sorted list?

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, lambda

I know this is simple, but my mind is playing tricks on me right now.  If we have a flat list of objects with the properties GroupSortIndex and ItemSortIndex (within the group) and we want to find the first item in the list, what's the Linq/lambda for that?

About all I can think of is (meta, not literal code...)

```
var soughtItem = Source.OrderBy(ItemSortIndex).OrderBy(GroupSortIndex).ToList()[0]
```

...but that just looks so wrong to me for some reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `IOrderedEnumerable.ThenBy` (Note: an `IOrderedEnumerable` is returned from `IEnumerable.OrderBy`):

```
var firstItem = source.OrderBy(s => s.GroupSortIndex)
                      .ThenBy(s => s.ItemSortIndex)
                      .First();
```

This orders first by the group and then by the item. You should use `FirstOrDefault` if the sequence can be empty. Otherwise `First` raises an exception.

(i've assumed that you want to order first by group and then by the item instead, since the ItemSortIndex is the index of the item within the group(as mentioned))

Comment: Have you changed your mind, is the order not correct because you've unaccept it?

Comment: No, order is correct.  I marked it before I verified it which isn't good S.O. etiquette, so I reversed it, built a test app, proved it, and as I originally thought, yours was the only one of the three answers that had the right order, so it's yours. (Tried to remove it before you noticed. Guess you're too fast! :)

Comment: Actually, really good find because thanks to you showing me this,  I now know about `IOrderedEnumerable`, which is what the `ThenBy` extension method hangs off of.  I was looking against `IEnumerable` and thus, didn't see it. I also updated your answer to correctly show that's the source instead of Enumerable as you mentioned. Again, thanks!

Comment: Ah ok, but an `IOrderedEnumerable<T>` inherits from `IEnumerable<T>`. Once you know the `ThenBy` (you can chain it as often as you want) you'll never forget it ;)

Comment: Definitely won't be forgetting that!  Thanks again!  Already in our production code working like a champ!

Answer (score 4):

Read post : [Default Extension methods](http://pranayamr.blogspot.in/2011/04/default-extension-methods.html) to get difference between first and firstordefault

you can use FirstOrDefualt() or First() function

```
var soughtItem = Source.OrderBy(ItemSortIndex).
                   ThenBy(GroupSortIndex).FirstOrDefualt();
if(soughtItem !=null)//advantage of using firstordefault
{
}
```

its better to use `FirstOrDefualt` because if there is no data it will return null intead of excetipn

Comment: Good answer, but not quite right.  Your group and item sorts are reversed.  I reversed them in mine but that was because I was doing two order-bys and (incorrectly) hoping it otherwise maintained the order.  The ThenBy made doing that unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

```
var soughtItem = Source
    .OrderBy(ItemSortIndex)
    .ThenBy(GroupSortIndex).First();
```

If `ItemSortIndex` and `GroupSortIndex` are properties instead of functions, then you need:

```
var soughtItem = Source
    .OrderBy(i => ItemSortIndex)
    .ThenBy(i => GroupSortIndex).First();
```

Comment: Same issue I called out with Pranay's answer.  Right concept, but the wrong order, so I had to give the answer to Tim.